# elasticache read and write data from lambda using AWS-SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, aws-sdk

I'm using NodeJS for my lambda function. currently I'm using NPM package for redis to connect and read/write data into elasticache. but it gives an internal server error.
in the aws-sdk NPM package also has some elasticache related methods, but I couldn't find any methods to set and get values to/from elasticache. what should I do for this?

Comment: Those methods in the AWS SDK are for creating and managing Elasticsearch servers. They are not for querying data inside the servers. You should focus on your current solution, and look at the AWS Lambda logs to see what the actual error is.

Comment: @MarkB thank you for the quick response. i'll check and find out about the error. So, what should i use for querying the data?. the NPM package for redis?. is it working with elasticache in lambda?

Comment: Yes you will most likely need to use an npm package for Redis. You'll have to package it correctly in your Lambda deployment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use npm package for [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) to read and write from Elasticache,
Here  is a sample code for get and set,

```
const redis = require("redis");

const client = redis.createClient({
    host: 'YOUR REDIS HOST',
    port: 6379
});

export.handler = async () => {
    await storeValue('sampleKey', 'sampleValue');
    const value = await getValue('sampleKey');
    return value;
}

const getValue = key => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.get(key, (error, response) => {
            if (error)
                reject(error);
            else
                resolve(response);
        });
    });
}

const storeValue = (key, value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.set(key, value, (error, response) => {
            if (error)
                reject(error);
            else
                resolve(response);
        });
    });
}
```